# Is there a better way to find out the correct CSS values for a 3D transformation, besides trial & error?

Tags: css, 3d, transform

I've got a 3D iPhone vector and I want to have a sprite animation of screens on top of it.
I'm creating a `div` as mask on top of the iPhone, with the sprite background (animating via transition & background-position).

However, the iPhone is already in the correct 3D position, but in able to use a sprite image in 3D with a mask, the div should be rotated 3D too. Too bad I'm already over an hour trying to figure out the correct values to position the div correctly on top of the iPhone.

I'm currently using the values of: `perspective`, `skew`, `rotateX`, `rotateY` & `rotateZ`.

Too bad Photoshop (CC) doesn't give perspective and XYZ-axis values when performing a perspective transformation, otherwise this would be very simple.

So who knows a great way to figure out the correct values, besides trial & error.

Note: I can't use a regular iPhone image and apply 3D values on it and after that, apply the same values to the mask on top of it, because that would mean you'd have a flat 3D object.

Thanks!

**current status**, with `perspective(1000px) rotate(-72deg) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(40deg) rotateZ(11deg) skew(0deg, 20deg);` coming from a standard 16:9 portrait image.
[image: Current status]

Comment: Give this a go: http://www.createcss3.com/

Comment: I'm already using that site for gathering CSS attribute resources - but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want some thing along the lines of:

```
-webkit-transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(-60deg);
-moz-transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(-60deg);
-o-transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(-60deg);
-ms-transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(-60deg);
transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(-60deg);
```

Given the fact the screen x and y axis are consistent at all four points you should be able to do this without using skew, and likely with a perspective of zero.

Once the eleemnt has been transformed correctly in 3d space, you can shift it on the x and y axis using the transform origin, e.g:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 20px 50%;
-moz-transform-origin: 20px 50%;
-o-transform-origin: 20px 50%;
-ms-transform-origin: 20px 50%;
transform-origin: 20px 50%;
```

Comment: I do agree that it should be possible without perspective and skew; the latter for sure. However, with just using the X, Y, Z axis it's quite difficult.

What is the functionality of transform-origin? I'm not 100% sure whether it's just X & Z positioning, or altering the 3D itself, which I'm already doing with XYZ rotation? - Thanks!

Comment: The origin is simply the positioning of the element vs the original 2d plane, so 'basically' moving the element up, down, left or right in the browser window.

Comment: Late reply, but after 2 hours of trial and error, i've got the code. It aint perfect, especially since I had to use scale in order to fit the box, because changing X and Y values resulted in a smaller div/image. In the end had to use perspective, X-Y-Z, Skew (about 5 degrees in totaal) and scale. - But thanks! :)